# minimum value in int array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, minimum

I need to find the minimum value in int array, but the answer it gives me is really odd and from that I cannot even judge where the error is, I would really appreciate help. Here is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int minVert(int minimum, int i) {
    int j, array[20];
    for (j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
        if (array[i] < minimum ) {
            minimum = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minimum;
}

int main(int k, int minimum) {
    int array[20];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        k = rand() % 1000 + 2;
        array[i] = k;
    }
    cout << "Tiek generets masivs..." << endl << "..." << endl << "..." << endl << "..." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Masiva elementi ir: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j <20; j++) {
        cout << array[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Masiva mazaka vertiba ir: " << endl << minimum << endl << endl;
    cout << "Nospiediet jebkuru taustinu, lai izietu no programmas" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's the result you're receiving. Please post it as well as the input

Comment: I don't see any initialization for `minimum`, and why do you have `j < 19` in your first `for` loop when your array has 20 elements?

Comment: Oh WTF you're passing `minimum` to main??! The arguments of main should be `int argc, char **argv`. If you wanna pass minimum as an argument to your prog, you want to use argv & argc like shown [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)

Comment: The result is random, as is the array's contents generated at random, one of the results is:
2653742

Comment: haha, `fatal error: 'conio.h' file not found`.

Comment: You have haphazardly included a combination of C and C++ headers. You shouldn't mix the two.

Comment: I am still learning and kind of gotten into a few chaotic problems. I am sorry for the sloppy code.

Comment: *"I need to find the minimum value in int array"* - `std::min_element` works just fine with arrays.

Comment: cout << "minumum is : " << min_element(array,array+20) << endl;
doesn't work, just shows as result - 0013FCC0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your trying to populate the array with random numbers and then find the minimum.

First remove those parameters from the main function if your not going to use them. You haven't really called the function you wrote in the main. so either write that inside the main or call that function.
i would suggest this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[5];
    int minimum;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    minimum = array[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "minumum is : " << minimum;
}
```

Comment: I need to calculate the minimum value in the array outside the main function, that right now is my biggest issue, among plenty other :D

Comment: Thank you for reducing the number of include files.  Hopefully the OP will recognize this.

Comment: @Royal:  Move the last `for` loop into a separate function.  Pass the array, and the number of elements.  Return the minimum value.

Comment: why array content is 5? " int array[5]; "

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>  int main(int k, int minimum){
> ```

This is illegal. The only valid signature for `main()` is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // ...
}
```

or leave out any parameters at all

```
int main() {
    // ...
}
```

In the first case `argc` contains the number of command line arguments passed, and `argv` is an array of `char*` pointers, that contain the arguments.

Note that `argv[0]` contains the name of the executed program itself.

Comment: Hi, nitpick:  There are at least 2 valid signatures for `main`.  The one you didn't specify is `int main(void)`. ;-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `void *argv` and `bool **argv` might also work, right? What about `int **argv`?

Comment: @theoden Seriously not! You're telling nonsense!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, why not? it simply specifies the container type.

Comment: @theoden It's a matter of standard specifications, and not what's the user  likes to specify!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, is it a compiler's dirty hack?

Comment: @theoden No, that's just illegal as specified in the c++ standards, period!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your minimum variable as `minimum = array[0]` so your code will become like follow

```
int minVert(int minimum, int i){

    int j, array[20];
    minimum = array[0];
    for (j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
       if (array[i] < minimum ) {
           minimum = array[i];
       }
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

And if you want to write a function to find the minimum from an array the best practice is to write a code which will take reference of the array and return the minimum value